# How to know that the root view controller view hierarchy has finished loading

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

Hi I have a `UINavigationController` I `initialise` it with a `rootViewController` I want to receive a call back after the `rootViewController` view hierarchy has completed loaded.

Currently, I am using `protocol` to achieve the same i.e.

I have a `protocol` named `LoadedInitialViewController`
Which defines a function as

```
func didFinishLoading()
```

When the root view controller has completed loading in `viewWillAppear` I call

```
self.delegate.didFinishLoading
```

The navigation controller receives this call and carrier out the operation I need. Although this works I was wondering if there are any navigation controller delegate provided methods that can help me achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Give the UINavigationController a `delegate`, and in that delegate implement `navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)`.